# Unable to resolve dependency tree after upgrading node, failing on node-sass

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, node-sass

After upgrading Node.js to the latest version, I start getting these error messages when I tried `npm audit fix --force`. It seems like I'm unable to fix my dependency tree issues. I've tried to search for solutions to this error extensively and tried many different solutions, but none worked. Should the only solution be downgrading back to an older Node.js version?

```
npm ERR! path /Users/Mac/Desktop/Projects/folder/Website/folder/node_modules/node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! Building: /usr/local/bin/node /Users/Mac/Desktop/Projects/folder/Website/folder/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '/usr/local/bin/node',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '/Users/Mac/Desktop/Projects/folder/Website/folder/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.7.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.13.0 | darwin | x64
npm ERR! gyp verb command rebuild []
npm ERR! gyp verb command clean []
npm ERR! gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
npm ERR! gyp verb command configure []
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` succeeded python2 /usr/bin/python2
npm ERR! gyp verb check python version `/usr/bin/python2 -c "import platform; print(platform.python_version());"` returned: "2.7.16\n"
npm ERR! gyp verb get node dir no --target version specified, falling back to host node version: 16.13.0
npm ERR! gyp verb command install [ '16.13.0' ]
npm ERR! gyp verb install input version string "16.13.0"
npm ERR! gyp verb install installing version: 16.13.0
npm ERR! gyp verb install --ensure was passed, so won't reinstall if already installed
npm ERR! gyp verb install version is already installed, need to check "installVersion"
npm ERR! gyp verb got "installVersion" 9
npm ERR! gyp verb needs "installVersion" 9
npm ERR! gyp verb install version is good
npm ERR! gyp verb get node dir target node version installed: 16.13.0
npm ERR! gyp verb build dir attempting to create "build" dir: /Users/Mac/Desktop/Projects/folder/Website/folder/node_modules/node-sass/build
npm ERR! gyp verb build dir "build" dir needed to be created? /Users/Mac/Desktop/Projects/folder/Website/filder/node_modules/node-sass/build
npm ERR! gyp verb build/config.gypi creating config file
npm ERR! gyp verb build/config.gypi writing out config file: /Users/Mac/Desktop/Projects/folder/Website/folder/node_modules/node-sass/build/config.gypi
npm ERR! (node:19391) [DEP0150] DeprecationWarning: Setting process.config is deprecated. In the future the property will be read-only.
npm ERR! (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
npm ERR! gyp verb config.gypi checking for gypi file: /Users/Mac/Desktop/Projects/folder/Website/folder/node_modules/node-sass/config.gypi
npm ERR! gyp verb common.gypi checking for gypi file: /Users/Mac/Desktop/Projects/folder/Website/folder/node_modules/node-sass/common.gypi
npm ERR! gyp verb gyp gyp format was not specified; forcing "make"
npm ERR! gyp info spawn /usr/bin/python2
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/Mac/Desktop/Projects/folder/Website/folder/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'make',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/Mac/Desktop/Projects/folder/Website/folder/node_modules/node-sass/build/config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/Mac/Desktop/Projects/folder/Website/folder/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/Mac/.node-gyp/16.13.0/include/node/common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/Users/Mac/.node-gyp/16.13.0',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/Users/Mac/Desktop/Projects/folder/Website/folder/node_modules/node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/Users/Mac/.node-gyp/16.13.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/Users/Mac/Desktop/Projects/folder/Website/folder/node_modules/node-sass',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables' found at '/'.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.DeveloperToolsCLILeo' found at '/'.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.DeveloperToolsCLI' found at '/'.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! gyp: No Xcode or CLT version detected!
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/Users/Mac/Desktop/Projects/folder/Website/folder/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:345:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:290:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Darwin 19.6.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/Users/Mac/Desktop/Projects/folder/Website/folder/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /Users/Mac/Desktop/Projects/folder/Website/folder/node_modules/node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.13.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.7.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/Mac/.npm/_logs/2021-11-24T18_21_54_491Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## First solution

Make sure your Node.js version is not superior to the [latest stable one](https://nodejs.org/en). For that you could use the [n](https://www.npmjs.com/package/n) package from `npm`:

```bash
npm install -g n
n stable
# if one of the commands does not pass, you may need to use sudo
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable
```

Then you would wanna use [sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass) package instead of [node-sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass), as it's deprecated. And for that, run those commands:

```bash
npm uninstall node-sass --save
npm install sass --save
```

## Second solution

If you need or want `node-sass` for some reason, you should downgrade your Node.js version, `v14`, for example. For that you can again use [n](https://www.npmjs.com/package/n) package from `npm`:

```bash
npm install -g n
n 14
# if one of the commands does not pass, you may need to use sudo
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n 14
```

Answer (score 0):

I got rid of everything and re-installed Xcode, Node and node-sass again, and the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I downgraded my node version from 16.17 to 14.20 with the help of nvm and it worked for me.
I had node-sass 8+.